# soup.find(class_="") not working with encrypted site

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape [Ksl](https://classifieds.ksl.com/search?category[]=&subCategory[]=&keyword=piano&priceFrom=&priceTo=&zip=&miles=25&sellerType[]=&marketType[]=Sale&hasPhotos[]=&postedTime[]=). As their website is encrypted I have to use Mozilla to scrape it normally. Here is what I have so far

```
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs

class AppURLopener(urllib.request.FancyURLopener):
version = "Mozilla/5.0"

opener = AppURLopener()
sauce = opener.open("https://classifieds.ksl.com/search?category[]=&subCategory[]=&keyword=piano&priceFrom=&priceTo=&zip=&miles=25&sellerType[]=&marketType[]=Sale&hasPhotos[]=&postedTime[]=").read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')
print(soup.find(class_="listing-item"))
```

When I search by classes using `soup.find(class_="")`
nothing happens, but when I use something like `soup.find(id="")` or `soup.find("div")` it works just fine.

I have used beautifulsoup a bit in the past and the only thing different in this code as opposed to code I have worked on in the past is Ksl's web encryption.

If anyone has a solution, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Opening the url in the browser results in blank page.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not use any browser simulator, you need to use a headers to access the content of that page. Moreover, the content you are interested in are javascript encrypted. However, the desired content are available within some script tag in that page, so you can fetch them using `requests` module along with `re` and `hjson` library. You can stick to `urllib` module as well if you do not wish to go for `requests`.

```
import re
import hjson
import requests

url = "https://classifieds.ksl.com/search?category[]=&subCategory[]=&keyword=piano&priceFrom=&priceTo=&zip=&miles=25&sellerType[]=&marketType[]=Sale&hasPhotos[]=&postedTime[]="

res = requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
items = hjson.loads(re.findall(r"window.renderSearchSection\(([\s\S]*?)\)</",res.text)[0])
for item in items['listings']:
    name = item['title']
    price = item['price']
    print(name,price)
```

Portion of output are like:

```
PIANO TUNER GOING OUT OF BUSINESS 1
Brodmann PE-187 Grand Piano 12500
Player piano 250
Antique Claw Foot Piano Stool (Doesn't Spin) 60
Free Player Piano 0
Baldwin Studio Piano with Bench and Music Books 375
Excellent condition  Brodmann electric piano 200
Casio Privia px-760 Piano/Keyboard 500
```

Comment: is there a way to make this work with bs4 functions?

Comment: You can't with bs4 in combination with requests. However, You can use bs4 in combination with selenium but that will be way slower. Thanks.